# Special character in JSON payload not processed successfully when running the script in JMeter

Tags: json, jmeter

When trying to process the JSON Message contains special character " ®"
which is actually a registered trademark symbol, failed with error when trying in JMeter. The same payload is working as expected in other tools like postman etc. Please advise on how to fix this issue in JMeter.

> Error:
>   {
>     "code": 400,
>     "errors": [
>       {
>         "key": "messages",
>         "message": "Unable to translate bytes [AE] at index 901 from specified code page to Unicode."
>       }
>     ]
>   }

Thanks
Bharath

Comment: can yoy show full stacktrace in jmeter.log ?

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce your issue, most probably something is wrong with your JMeter Configuration, i.e. try setting `file.encoding` and `client.encoding.override` [JVM System Properties](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html) to `UTF-8`

[image: Java System Encoding UTF-8]

You can set aforementioned properties in *system.properties* file (located in JMeter's "bin" folder), JMeter restart will be required to pick the properties up.

---

Also given you can execute the same request using Postman you can just record it with JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder).

1. Configure JMeter for recording using [JMeter Templates](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-save-%E2%80%98loads%E2%80%99-time-using-jmeters-template-feature) feature (from JMeter's main menu choose `File -> Templates -> Recording -> Create` and start the HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder
2. Configure Postman for recording. In order to set it for using JMeter as a proxy launch it with `--proxy-server` option like:

   ```
   C:\Users\your_user_name_here\AppData\Local\Postman\app-x.x.x\Postman.exe --proxy-server=localhost:8888
   ```

See [How to configure Postman Native Client App to use an external proxy](http://blog.eviltester.com/2016/12/how-to-configure-postman-native-client.html) for more information.

Comment: Thank you. Added UTF-8 in the Unicode Encode and it is working as expected. Thanks everyone